# org-mode shell table results: content around quotes is stripped out

Tags: shell, csv, org-mode

Returning shell results into a table, content around double quotes is deleted.

```
#+begin_src shell :results table
echo 'I "want" it all'
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| want |
```

Is there a way to make org preserve the whole string?

Comment: Weird! That honestly seems like a bug to me. You'll probably get some more feedback if you post in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results table
echo "I "want" it all"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| I want it all |
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to preserve the quotes around `want` as well. Any idea how to do that?